# Migration from NamingStrategy in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working on a Java project that was started many years ago, and all of the original developers are long gone. One of the classes I inherited is an implementation of the Hibernate NamingStrategy interface.

At this point NamingStrategy is deprecated and I'd like to transition to something that's still supported going forward. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this. I've seen two families of suggestions on the topic: most people online recommend the use of ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy, while the Hibernate Javadocs recommend the use of NamingStrategyDelegator.

In both cases, the information available to an unsophisticated Hibernate user is not sufficient to understand how to do the migration. Just as an example: NamingStrategy has 10 methods, each of which takes String arguments. PhysicalNamingStrategy has 5 methods, none of which takes a String argument.

Can anyone assist me in figuring out how to address this safely? In case it helps, I attach our NamingStrategy implementation below.

```
package gov.nasa.ziggy.services.database;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.AssertionFailure;
import org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper;

import gov.nasa.ziggy.util.StringUtils;
import gov.nasa.ziggy.util.StringUtils.TextCase;

/**
 * This class implements {@link org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy} for the database naming
 * conventions defined for the Ziggy project. Essentially, this consists of converting the Java
 * camel-case names to an all-caps with underscores format.
 * <p>
 * This code is based on {@link org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy}, the main difference being
 * that names that are explicitly defined in the code annotations (like {@link Table},
 * {@link Column}, etc.) are not modified.
 *
 */
public class ZiggyNamingStrategy implements NamingStrategy {
    /**
     * A convenient singleton instance
     */
    public static final NamingStrategy INSTANCE = new ZiggyNamingStrategy();

    /**
     * Return the unqualified class name, mixed case converted to underscores
     */
    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String className) {
        return addUnderscores(StringHelper.unqualify(className));
    }

    /**
     * Return the full property path with underscore seperators, mixed case converted to underscores
     */
    @Override
    public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
        return addUnderscores(StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName));
    }

    /**
     * This method is called for names explicitly defined in the annotations. Leave the name alone!
     */
    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName) {
        return tableName;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called for names explicitly defined in the annotations. Leave the name alone!
     */
    @Override
    public String columnName(String columnName) {
        return columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public String collectionTableName(String ownerEntity, String ownerEntityTable,
        String associatedEntity, String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {
        String s = tableName(ownerEntityTable + '_' + propertyToColumnName(propertyName));
        System.out.println("collection table name " + s);
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Return the argument
     */
    @Override
    public String joinKeyColumnName(String joinedColumn, String joinedTable) {
        String s = addUnderscores(joinedTable) + "_" + addUnderscores(joinedColumn);
        System.out.println("joinkey column name " + s);
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Return the property name or propertyTableName
     */
    @Override
    public String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName,
        String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {
        String header = propertyName != null ? StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName)
            : propertyTableName;
        if (header == null) {
            throw new AssertionFailure("NamingStrategy not properly filled");
        }
        String s = addUnderscores(propertyTableName) + "_" + addUnderscores(referencedColumnName);
        if (s.equals("PI_PS_NAME_NAME")) {
            System.out.println("foreign key column name " + s);
        }
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Return the column name or the unqualified property name
     */
    @Override
    public String logicalColumnName(String columnName, String propertyName) {
        String s = StringHelper.isNotEmpty(columnName) ? columnName
            : StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName);
        if (columnName == null) {
            System.out
                .println("logical column name " + columnName + "  " + propertyName + "  " + s);
        }
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Returns either the table name if explicit or if there is an associated table, the
     * concatenation of owner entity table and associated table otherwise the concatenation of owner
     * entity table and the unqualified property name
     */
    @Override
    public String logicalCollectionTableName(String tableName, String ownerEntityTable,
        String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {
        if (tableName != null) {
            return tableName;
        }
        // use of a stringbuffer to workaround a JDK bug
        String s = new StringBuffer(ownerEntityTable).append("_")
            .append(associatedEntityTable != null ? associatedEntityTable
                : StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName))
            .toString();
        System.out.println("logical collection table name " + s);
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Return the column name if explicit or the concatenation of the property name and the
     * referenced column
     */
    @Override
    public String logicalCollectionColumnName(String columnName, String propertyName,
        String referencedColumn) {
        String s = StringHelper.isNotEmpty(columnName) ? columnName
            : StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName) + "_" + referencedColumn;
        if (!s.equals(columnName)) {
            System.out.println("logical collection column name " + columnName + "  " + propertyName
                + "  " + referencedColumn + "  " + s);
        }
        return s;
    }

    protected String addUnderscores(String original) {
        return StringUtils.camelCaseToUnderscores(original, TextCase.UPPER);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mind just getting rid of this controversial feature? the purpose of naming strategy is to make technology attractive to newbies, i.e. "you didn't write anything db-specific and it works somehow, wow". Just define actual table and column names for your entities.

Comment: That's terrible advice, Andrey. Naming strategies are great, and there's nothing at all "controversial" about them.

Comment: @GavinKing can't agree with you. first of all, naming strategies do not take into account "features" of underlying DBs (max identifier length, case-sensitivity, reserved words, etc), that in turn means sooner or later you will be forced to explicitly define suitable identifiers for some cases - that turns the code into a mess: somewhere we define  identifiers, somewhere don't. 2. If application is mature enough it's DB should be under control of migration tool, since we use explicit identifiers there, there is no point to not use them in entity mapping.

Comment: and at third, when we are performing root cause analysis of DB issues that is much simpler and faster to just perform search in IDE using basic string match rather than trying to guess what entity relates to the problematic table.

Comment: Fine, that's your preference, and your opinion, and you have some at least arguable reasons for holding that opinion. I disagree with your reasoning, but there's not enough space here to make the case. That doesn't make this feature "controversial".

Comment: Getting rid of NamingStrategy: the problem is the legacy database schema. If we get rid of the naming strategy we need to write a migrator script that translates all the tables, columns, etc., to the strategy-free versions. That might be the easiest and safest route, but it doesn't feel easy or safe to me.

Comment: Relatedly: I can't be the only person who is in this predicament! This is why I'm a little surprised that there isn't a "recipe" available for migrating away from NamingStrategy. It's inefficient for each user who needs to stop using a deprecated interface to separately go to the effort of inventing a migration. So much easier if the experts say, "replace method X with the combination of methods Y and Z as specified below," etc.

Comment: @quarkpt you don not need to migrate data at all, just place correct/actual `@Table`/`@Column`/`@JoinColumn` annotations over classes and fields.

Answer (score 2):

**Short story**

Stay clear of naming strategies in `Hibernate`, this feature is unstable, unreliable, unmaintainable and, furthermore, it increases technical debt (that is exactly what you actually get: *at this point NamingStrategy is deprecated and I'd like to transition to something that's still supported going forward*), moreover, even `Hibernate` team admits this feature is [unstable](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/35f0c57f07a7e3510b07b6fd8b0f2f469fec1e38/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy.java#L43):

```java
@Incubating
public interface PhysicalNamingStrategy {
```

[@Incubating](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/Incubating.java):

> Marks certain of packages, types, etc. as incubating, potentially recursively. Incubating indicates something that is still being actively developed and therefore may change at a later time; a "tech preview".

> Users of these types and methods are considered early adopters who help shape the final definition of these types/methods, along with the needs of consumers.

The best option is to place valid/actual `@Table` and `@Column` annotations over related entities/fields and close that technical debt - that is your responsibility, as a developer, to keep the code maintainable.

`Hibernate` team had unintentionally opened Pandora's box, and upcoming release 6.2 is a best candidate to close it, the only action  required is to replace `@Incubating` with `@Deprecated`.

**Long story**

I. naming strategies are not portable across JPA implementations, for example if you try to find how to implement the same in `eclipselink` you may find [something like](https://gist.github.com/ganeshs/c0deb77ffae33dee4555):

```java
    @Override
    public void customize(Session session) throws SQLException {
        for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : session.getDescriptors().values()) {
            // Only change the table name for non-embedable entities with no
            // @Table already
            if (!descriptor.getTables().isEmpty() && descriptor.getAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(descriptor.getTableName())) {
                String tableName = addUnderscores(descriptor.getTableName());
                descriptor.setTableName(tableName);
                for (IndexDefinition index : descriptor.getTables().get(0).getIndexes()) {
                    index.setTargetTable(tableName);
                }
            }
            for (DatabaseMapping mapping : descriptor.getMappings()) {
                // Only change the column name for non-embedable entities with
                // no @Column already

                if (mapping instanceof AggregateObjectMapping) {
                    for (Association association : ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getAggregateToSourceFieldAssociations()) {
                        DatabaseField field = (DatabaseField) association.getValue();
                        field.setName(addUnderscores(field.getName()));
                        
                        for (DatabaseMapping attrMapping : session.getDescriptor(((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getReferenceClass()).getMappings()) {
                            if (attrMapping.getAttributeName().equalsIgnoreCase((String) association.getKey())) {
                                ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).addFieldTranslation(field, addUnderscores(attrMapping.getAttributeName()));
                                ((AggregateObjectMapping) mapping).getAggregateToSourceFields().remove(association.getKey());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mapping instanceof ObjectReferenceMapping) {
                    for (DatabaseField foreignKey : ((ObjectReferenceMapping) mapping).getForeignKeyFields()) {
                        foreignKey.setName(addUnderscores(foreignKey.getName()));
                    }
                } else if (mapping instanceof DirectMapMapping) {
                    for (DatabaseField referenceKey : ((DirectMapMapping) mapping).getReferenceKeyFields()) {
                        referenceKey.setName(addUnderscores(referenceKey.getName()));
                    }
                    for (DatabaseField sourceKey : ((DirectMapMapping) mapping).getSourceKeyFields()) {
                        sourceKey.setName(addUnderscores(sourceKey.getName()));
                    }
                } else {
                    DatabaseField field = mapping.getField();
                    if (field != null && !mapping.getAttributeName().isEmpty() && field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(mapping.getAttributeName())) {
                        field.setName(addUnderscores(mapping.getAttributeName()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry, but that is not kind of code I would like to maintain, on the other hand, I can definitely say that `eclipselink` is not `JPA` implementation I would like to deal with - the problem is it strictly follows `JPA` specification (`Hibernate` is definitely more flexible and extensible). However, you need to keep in mind that naming strategies applies globally, so, when you adopting third-party library or a plugin, based on `JPA`, you might get "surprised" that that library or plugin conflicts with your naming strategy.

II. predictable names make sense:

- when you diagnose performance issues, DBAs typically tell you what queries are slow, after that you need somehow determine what code produces those slow queries (there we need to say "thanks" to `spring-data-jpa` for their naming convention), and that takes a time to match SQL query to JPQL query, and usage of naming strategies is not your friend there. If you think SQL queries do not make sense and you can collect performance statistics using `micrometer`/`grafana`, I have bad news for you: [that does not work in Hibernate](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/performance-issues-when-enabling-micrometer-metrics/7035)
- naming strategies somehow try to cover table and column names, but do not cover index names, which is actually important from performance perspective: try to guess what columns are covered by index with name like `UK_jymdjmt0g2vxkk0fp56xlhjud`. Need to ask DBA? OK, your code is unmaintainable... Maintain single source of truth about database and keep as much as possible information in the source code
- if you have no idea about column and table names in database you lack a lot of important things, some examples:

  - you can't validate database state (no need to tell about `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` - it's functionality is extremely limited)
  - you can't translate database errors into user-friendly messages (how is it possible to convert something like  "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UK_jymdjmt0g2vxkk0fp56xlhjud" into "user with name XXX already exists"?)
  - you can't determine maximum allowed length of text fields an precision of numeric fields
- and finally, how am I supposed to write SQL-queries, migration scenarios, etc, if I have no idea about target column and table names?

III. the feature is broken

Little quiz:

**Q**: what do you need to specify in `@Column` definition when `InheritanceType=JOINED`:

```
    /**
     * (Optional) The name of the table that contains the column. 
     * If absent the column is assumed to be in the primary table.
     */
    String table() default "";
```

**A**: `Hibernate` accepts both logical and physical table names.

**Q**: what do you need to specify in `@Synchronize` annotation if you created a "view" and you would like to keep view state in sync with persistence context:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Synchronize {
    /**
     * Table names.
     */
    String[] value();
}
```

**A**: [in **Hibernate 4** you was need to specify physical table names, in **Hibernate 5.1+** you need to specify logical table names](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10002)

**Q**: you need to trigger a SQL procedure/update statement and you would like to keep its execution in sync with persistence context, what do you need to specify in [`org.hibernate.query.native.spaces` hint](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14325) (another one concept, which is described nowhere):

```java
    /**
     * Hint for specifying query spaces to be applied to a NativeQuery.
     *
     * Passed value can be any of:<ul>
     *     <li>List of the spaces</li>
     *     <li>array of the spaces</li>
     *     <li>String as "whitespace"-separated list of the spaces</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * Note that the passed space need not match any real spaces/tables in
     * the underlying query.  This can be used to completely circumvent
     * the auto-flush checks as well as any cache invalidation that might
     * occur as part of a flush.  See {@link org.hibernate.query.SynchronizeableQuery}
     * and {@link FlushMode#MANUAL} for more information.
     *
     * @see org.hibernate.query.SynchronizeableQuery
     * @see #HINT_FLUSH_MODE
     */
    String HINT_NATIVE_SPACES = "org.hibernate.query.native.spaces";
```

**A**: you need to specify everything you might find feasible: physical table names, logical table names, entity names, cache region names, your mother maiden name, name of your first pet, etc. - nobody knows how to use that properly, Thorben Janssen, for example, believes [we need to pass class name there](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-query-spaces/), `Hibernate` assumes that [query space is actually a physical table name](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/662594fd5f7f4c91de5ae11e7c81924c9915c0b1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/sql/internal/NativeQueryImpl.java#L1193) (how is it possible to pass **Entity Class** as hint value using `@jakarta.persistence.QueryHint` annotation?) Even `Hibernate` project lead [has no idea about how to use that properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192819/3426309):

> A logical name is a name used to within annotations of Java code and XML mapping documents

In case of `@jakarta.persistence.QueryHint` we need to use **physical table names**! Where is the logic???

Answer (score 1):

So I *very* recently rewrote the Javadoc for these interfaces, to make it easier to understand the difference. But that new Javadoc isn't available online yet, because the release of 6.2 final slipped by a week.

So let me copy/paste the explanation from the Javadoc here, HTH.

##### Package `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming`

This API allows intervention by generic code in the process of determining the names of
database objects (tables, columns, and constraints).

Name determination happens in two phases:

1. *Logical naming* is the process of applying naming rules to determine the
             names of objects which were not explicitly assigned names in the O/R mapping.

   Here, this is the responsibility of an implementation of
             `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy`.
2. *Physical naming* is the process of applying additional rules to transform
             a logical name into an actual "physical" name that will be used in the database.
             For example, the rules might include things like using standardized abbreviations,
             or trimming the length of identifiers.

   Here, this is the responsibility of an implementation of
             `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

##### `ImplicitNamingStrategy`

A set of rules for determining the logical name of a mapped relational database object when the mapping for an element of the Java domain model is not explicitly specified, neither in annotations of the Java code, nor in an XML-based mapping document.

For example, if a Java class annotated `@Entity` has no `@Table` annotation, then `determinePrimaryTableName` is called with an `ImplicitEntityNameSource` providing access to information about the Java class and its entity name.

On the other hand, when a logical name is explicitly specified, for example, using `@Table` to specify the table name, or `@Column` to specify a column name, the `PhysicalNamingStrategy` is not called and has no opportunity to intervene in the determination of the logical name.

However, a further level of processing is applied to the resulting logical names by a `PhysicalNamingStrategy` in order to determine the "finally final" physical names in the relational database schema.
Whenever reasonable, the use of a custom `ImplicitNamingStrategy` is highly recommended in preference to tedious and repetitive explicit table and column name mappings. It's anticipated that most projects using Hibernate will feature a custom implementation of `ImplicitNamingStrategy`.

An `ImplicitNamingStrategy` may be selected using the configuration property `"hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy"`.

##### `PhysicalNamingStrategy`

A set of rules for determining the physical names of objects in a relational database schema from the logical names specified by the object/relational mappings.

- A physical name is a name used to interact with the database, and will always be used in generated SQL, both DML and DDL.
- A logical name is a name used to within annotations of Java code and XML mapping documents.

Logical names provide an additional level of indirection between the mappings and the database schema, and a `PhysicalNamingStrategy` even allows the use of more "natural" naming within the mappings in cases where the relational schema features especially inelegant legacy naming conventions. For example, it could shield the mappings from old-fashioned practices like prefixing table names with `TBL_`.

Note, however, that handwritten native SQL must be written in terms of physical names, so the abstraction here is in some sense "incomplete".

A `PhysicalNamingStrategy` may be selected using the configuration property `"hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"`.

Comment: In the third paragraph of the ImplicitNamingStrategy section, you say "... the PhysicalNamingStrategy is not called..." Did you mean to say ImplicitNamingStrategy here? If not, you should probably explain how the ImplicitNamingStrategy section is suddenly talking about PhysicalNamingStrategy.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that, thanks.