Hibernate Synchronization :- find() vs createQuery()
I am currently learning about the @Synchronize in Hibernate. So, in this I encountered a problem. I am having two Entity Classes:- Subject.java and RetrieveSubject.java.
Subject.java
package org.example.bean;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

@Entity(name = "subject_entity")
@Table(name = "SUBJECTS",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"subjectName"}))
@Data
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long subjectId;

    String subjectName;
}


RetrieveSubject.java
package org.example.bean;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Synchronize;

@Entity(name="retrievesubject")
@Getter
@Subselect(value="select s.subjectId as sid ,s.subjectName as subname from tbl_subjects s")
@Synchronize(value={"TBL_SUBJECTS"},logical = false)
@Immutable
public class RetrieveSubject {

    @Id
    Long sid;
    String subname;
}


So in the RetrieveSubject.java file, it is a immutable entity which is acting like a View, so whenever I am requesting the RetrieveSubject Entity from Hibernate (using entityManager.createQuery()), it should synchronize the Subject Entity( Table name:- TBL_SUBJECTS).
Now please see the below code:-
package org.example.service;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.example.bean.RetrieveSubject;
import org.example.bean.Subject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SubjectService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Subject");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of subjects:-");
        int noofSubjects = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        String subjectName="";

        for(int i=1; i<=noofSubjects; i++){
           System.out.print("Enter the subject name:-");
           subjectName = sc.nextLine();

            Subject subject = new Subject();
            subject.setSubjectName(subjectName);

            EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            entityTransaction.begin();
            entityManager.persist(subject);
            System.out.println("Subject persisted with id:-"+subject.getSubjectId());
            entityTransaction.commit();
            
        }

       EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

       entityTransaction.begin();

        Subject randomSubject = entityManager.find(Subject.class,4);
        System.out.println("randomSubjectName:-"+randomSubject.getSubjectName());
        randomSubject.setSubjectName("Chemistry");


        RetrieveSubject retrieveSubject2 = entityManager.find(RetrieveSubject.class,4);//findline
        System.out.println(retrieveSubject2.getSubname());

        Query retrieveSubject = entityManager.createQuery("select r from retrievesubject r where r.sid=:id");
        List< RetrieveSubject> retrieveSubjectList = retrieveSubject.setParameter("id",4).getResultList();
        for(RetrieveSubject retrieveSubject1 : retrieveSubjectList)
            System.out.println(retrieveSubject1.getSid()+"----"+retrieveSubject1.getSubname());

        entityTransaction.commit();
    }
}

In the above code, I am first getting the no of Subjects and then the name of the Subjects and then storing them in the DB.
Till that it is fine.
Now, see the below lines in the above code:-
Subject randomSubject = entityManager.find(Subject.class,4);
        System.out.println("randomSubjectName:-"+randomSubject.getSubjectName());
        randomSubject.setSubjectName("Chemistry");

taking the 4th subject (primary key value is 4) and set the subjectName to Chemistry.
After that I am calling entityManager.find(RetrieveSubject.class,4) and the output is (lets say the 4th subject I gave as Physics):-
Physics

This is fine as find() does not flush the changes before executing.
Now after this in the following lines:-
 Query retrieveSubject = entityManager.createQuery("select r from retrievesubject r where r.sid=:id");
        List< RetrieveSubject> retrieveSubjectList = retrieveSubject.setParameter("id",4).getResultList();
        for(RetrieveSubject retrieveSubject1 : retrieveSubjectList)
            System.out.println(retrieveSubject1.getSid()+"----"+retrieveSubject1.getSubname());

I am creating a query and trying to fetch the 4th entity, but here also I am getting the output as Physics. But is should Chemistry right??
Even though Hibernate is flushing the changes by calling the below update query before running the select:-
/* update
        for org.example.bean.Subject */update TBL_SUBJECTS 
    set
        subjectName=? 
    where
        subjectId=?

I am getting incorrect output.
But If I comment the line entityManager.find(RetrieveSubject.class,4) and then execute the code(assume I gave the 4th subjectName as Physics) , I am getting the correct output as Chemistry after the query.getResultList() is executed.
So can anyone please tell me why this mismatch is happening. Why the output is different when find() + createQuery() is present and when only createQuery() is present??

@Synchronize(value={"TBL_SUBJECTS"},logical = false)  - AFAIK, nobody knows how it is supposed to work, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75199332/3426309, try to set different parameters first.

I am not able to get what you mean by "try setting different parameter". Moreover, I have doubt on find() vs createQuery(). Please check my question once.

the A for your Q is following: that is expected the query results you observe do contain entity states stored in session-level cache, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77430916/3426309 - "if entity to be retrieved is already present in persistent context, Hibernate won't refresh its state using DB data, such behaviour seems to be weird". However, the problem is HBN does not invalidate "derived" entities for some reason, that is either a bug in HBN or a bug in your configuration: try to change value={"TBL_SUBJECTS"} to value={"SUBJECTS"}, play with logical = false to eliminate 2nd

To go by what by say, then if when I do entity.createQuery() that time Hibernate updates the persistence context with new Subject Chemistry,  then why the same is not reflecting in the result of entity.createQuery().getResultList() as it should retrieve it from Persistence Context only??
